# For loop in json objects

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I want to for loop in the for following json data.
The console.log is working but is not working in the javascript function.
I want the for for loop to work in the javascript function. 
I want the results in the javascript function to be like

```
<script>
(function() {
      var questions = [ {
      question: "What is the value of 2 * 4";
      choices :[4, 8, 99, 11];
      correctAnswer: 1;},
{
      question: "What is the value of 2 * 8";
      choices :[4, 8, 16, 11];
      correctAnswer: 2;},

      ];

</script>
```

But am getting error in the console.
console error "expected expression, got keyword 'for'" these are my codes

```
<?php
$json_codes = array();


$sql = "SELECT  id, instructions,  quiz_question, correct, wrong, wrong1, wrong2  FROM student_quiz WHERE  subject ='SOCIAL STUDIES' AND type = 'challenge' ";
$results = $pdo->query($sql);
$results->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $results->fetch()) {
    $json_array['instructions'] = $row['instructions'];
    $json_array['quiz_question'] = $row['quiz_question'];
    $json_array['correct'] = $row['correct'];
    $json_array['wrong'] = $row['wrong'];
    $json_array['wrong1'] = $row['wrong1'];
    $json_array['wrong2'] = $row['wrong2'];
    array_push($json_codes,$json_array);
}

echo json_encode($json_codes);

?>
<script>
         var obj = <?php echo json_encode($json_codes);?>;

(function() {
  var questions = [ 

  for(a=0; a<obj.length; a++){
         document.write(obj[a]);

         }

  ];
```

Comment: You're going to need to say what you expect it to do and what it's doing instead.

Answer (score 0):

You do try to express a loop in a definition scope of an array. This is a syntax error.

I recommend to use `for ( var something in obj )` or `for ( var something of obj )` instead of utilizing incrementor-driven `for`-loops. Depending on what you want to do, this might be at first have an impact to the loop performance and at least those `for`-loops are harder to read (and maintain) than `for ( ... in ... )` or `for ( ... of ... )`.

You should get aware of how the JavaScript-syntax works. Definitions of arrays are restricted to associations, you can not place processing instructions like loops inside of array defintions (except the spread operator). You have to run them after the definition when migrating more data to the array/object using a loop.

At least, you should consider to not place definitions outside of the `(function() { ... })();` instruction, those instructions may not being affected by `use strict`-directives or the lazy execution model and scope exclusion this instruction does follow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick basic way to get your data from the PHP side to the JavaScript side.  Check hte comments - I changed your query slightly

```
<?php
$json_codes = array();

// note slight change in query
$sql = "SELECT instructions, quiz_question, correct, wrong, wrong1, wrong2  FROM student_quiz WHERE  subject ='SOCIAL STUDIES' AND type = 'challenge' ";
$results = $pdo->query($sql);
$results->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $results->fetch()) {
    // the only var you weren't using from the select
    // was the primary key/id, 
    $json_codes[] = $row;
}

// we now have an indexed array of associative arrays
// each of which represents a row from the db
// and we make a json string out of the array
$json_string=json_encode($json_codes);

?>

<script>
    var data=JSON.parse('<?php print($json_string);  ?>');
    alert(data[0].quiz_question);
</script>
```

Now that you can access the data from PHP via JavaScript, I'd look at doing something with one of the extended JS engines like Angular, etc.

```
<?php
$json_codes = array();

// note slight change in query
$sql = "SELECT instructions, quiz_question, correct, wrong, wrong1, wrong2  FROM student_quiz WHERE  subject ='SOCIAL STUDIES' AND type = 'challenge' ";
$results = $pdo->query($sql);
$results->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $results->fetch()) {
    // the only var you weren't using from the select
    // was the primary key/id, 
    $json_codes[] = $row;
}

// we now have an indexed array of associative arrays
// each of which represents a row from the db
// and we make a json string out of the array
$json_string=json_encode($json_codes);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.data = JSON.parse('<?php print($json_string); ?>');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="datum in data">
                    {{datum.text}}    
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="datum in data">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="prop in datum">
                            {{prop}}
                        </li> 
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```